# Best way to remove a leading zero after formatting a date in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got a date format template that I'm passing a date value to in the format YYYYMMDD

The template is the following:

```
<xsl:template name="formatDate">
    <xsl:param name="date" />
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date, 1, 4)" />
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($date, 5, 2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($date, 7, 2)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($month, '/', $day, '/', $year)" />
</xsl:template>
```

This would return the string 20131004 as 10/04/2013 which is correct.

What I need to do though is if the $month has a leading zero, to remove it. For example, 20130930 would be 09/30/2013 when I would prefer 9/30/2013.

What's the most efficient way to do that? I could do a choose/when before I set the value of the variable but I'm trying to do it in the proper manner with xslt (I'm still trying to get into it, it's coming along).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could utilize number() function

```
<xsl:variable name="month" select="number(substring($date, 5, 2))" />
<xsl:variable name="day" select="number(substring($date, 7, 2))" />
```

It should remove leading zero.